# Syntax for extracting string array from srv response in C++

Tags: ros, array

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to call a service and get a response from my ROS package. The specific srv is gazebo_msgs/GetWorldProperties, which is as follows:

```
---
float64 sim_time
string[] model_names
bool rendering_enabled
bool success
string status_message
```

I can receive the response, but I cannot figure out how to extract the string array ("model_names") from it in C++. Could anyone give a snippet example of code that would allow me to loop through this string array? The current code (which I just took a wild guess at, but obviously doesn't work) is as follows:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include <gazebo_msgs/GetWorldProperties.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "simWrapper");
    ros::NodeHandle n;
    ros::ServiceClient client = n.serviceClient<gazebo_msgs::GetWorldProperties>("gazebo/get_world_properties");
    gazebo_msgs::GetWorldProperties worldPropSrv;
    if (client.call(worldPropSrv))
    {
        std::vector<String> models = worldPropSrv.response.model_names;
        ROS_INFO("Number of models: %i", models.size());
    }
    else
    {
        ROS_ERROR("Failed to call service get_world_properties");
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206446/syntax-for-extracting-string-array-from-srv-response-in-c++/) by [Jordan9](https://answers.ros.org/users/22059/jordan9/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2015-04-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS' built-in `string` msg type is mapped onto `std::string` in C++, while ROS msg arrays are mapped onto `std::vector<T>` (from [wiki/msg - 2.1.1 Field Types](http://wiki.ros.org/msg#Field_Types)). Changing `std::vector<String>` to `std::vector<std::string>` should work (but in this case the copy is unnecessary, you could just work directly with the message).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jordan9](https://answers.ros.org/users/22059/jordan9/) on 2015-04-03**:
Thank you, that makes way more sense now!

**Comment by [Will Chamberlain](https://answers.ros.org/users/21723/will-chamberlain/) on 2016-02-01**:
I'm with Jordan9 on this one: I'm pretty new to C++ and to me that typing  is *not* obvious from  [wiki/msg - 2.1.1 Field Types](http://wiki.ros.org/msg#Field_Types).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-02-01**:
While I can sympathise, the information given in the wiki should be more than sufficient when starting with ROS, but already knowing some C++. The *Array handling* section clearly states that arrays are mapped onto `std::vector`, with `string` mapped onto `std::string`. The rest is normal C++.